Paho MQTT messages accumulated on RabbitMQ
I have a Paho client subscriber on an MQTT enabled RabbitMQ broker. The subscriber code looks like:
 def _retry_with_backoff(
        self,
        func: Callable[..., None],
        kwargs: dict[str, any],
        current_retry: int = 0,
        max_retries: int = 5,
        backoff: int = 2,
    ):
        try:
            func(**kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if current_retry < max_retries:
                time_to_sleep: int = backoff * current_retry
                time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
                opt_message = kwargs.get("message", None)
                message_id = (
                    opt_message.mid
                    if opt_message is not None and isinstance(opt_message, MQTTMessage)
                    else -1
                )
                logger.error(
                    "Message processing with ID %s from topic %s failed with exception %s. "
                    "Retrying after %d seconds. Current retry is %d...",
                    message_id,
                    self.get_topic(),
                    e,
                    time_to_sleep,
                    current_retry,
                )
                self._retry_with_backoff(func, kwargs, current_retry + 1, max_retries, backoff)
            else:
                logger.exception("Max retries reached. Message will be ignored.")

def on_message(self, client, userdata, message: MQTTMessage):
    self._retry_with_backoff(
            func=_on_message,
            kwargs=dict(client=client, userdata=userdata, message=message),
   )
def _on_message(client, userdata, message: MQTTMessage):
      try:
          self.process(message.payload)
      except Exception as e:
          raise e
      finally:
           logger.debug()
   

I cannot see any exceptions being produced from this piece of code. Even in situations when an error/exception is produced, the except clauses should catch it and not propagate it.
Nevertheless, when a google.protobuf.message.DecodeError is produced, it seems like messages are accumulated in the queue corresponding to the consumer.
I think that I am catching all exceptions/errors which should translate as an ACK to the broker. Am I wrong?

What version of the Paho client are you using?
Add a extra try/catch block to the on_message callback.
The Paho client will silently catch exceptions thrown in callbacks if not caught and handled explicitly.

Thank you for the reply. The on_message only calls _retry_with_backoff which is a try/catch block. You think that this is not enough?

Add the extra try/catch just to make sure
